# How can I format a String number to have commas in android Edit Field

Tags: java, android, string, format

For what function I can use in android to display the number into different formats.

For eg: 
If I enter 1000 then it should display like this 1,000.
If I enter 10000 then it should display like this 10,000.
If I enter 1000000 then it should display like this 1,000,000.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

You could use `DecimalFormat` and just format the number

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###");
String yourFormattedString = formatter.format(100000);
```

The result will be

- `1,000,000` for 1000000
- `10,000` for 10000
- `1,000` for 1000

**Update 12/02/2019**

This `String.format("%,d", number)` would be a better(less hardcoded) solution as indicated in the comments below by @DreaminginCode so I thought I would add it here as an alternative

Comment: but if i enter 100000 it displaying 100,000 instead i need like this 1,00,000, is it possible?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? 100,000 is standard. Try moving the comma in the hash format like this #,##,###. Don't know if it will work but you can give it a try.

Comment: @Neil, the standard is only valid for specific countries. Like for example, India has a different standard and is of the format #,##,###

Comment: Not to mention [countries using dot `.` as thousands separator](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html). This is such a bad but popular hard-coding answer. Developers should always respect user's locale unless there's a very good reason for not doing so.

Comment: @dreamingincode this answer, answers the question. If the question gave more insight into the actual problem the answer might have been different. It is not my place to judge good or bad practice with insufficient information. Practice can only be judged in practice. I agree that using locale would be a better solution if the application was to be used world wide.

Comment: It answers the question but answering a question doesn't automatically make it a good answer. And when information is insufficient, I believe one as a programmer should assume less instead of more. Answers that use hard-coding can break easily when assumptions change, and in this case hard-coding is especially bad for any i18n related code because there can always be future people trying to add i18n and it would be their wtf moment. Not to mention even just a larger number can break this. For a much simpler solution, you could have used `String.format("%,d", number)` which is short and correct

Comment: can I add decimal behind like 1,000,000.50 ? Or 1M.50 ?  @Neil

Answer (score 51):

try this one hope it will help.

```
 System.out.println(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(1000));
```

Comment: To be safe, you'll likely want to use the device's locale, not always US. Locale current = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;

Comment: Locale.getDefault() is an even easier way to get device locale.

Comment: According to [Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html), parameterless `get...Instance()` methods use default locale by default.

Answer (score 15):

```
private String getFormatedAmount(int amount){
  return NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(amount);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
int[] numbersToFormat = new int[]
  { 1, 10, 100, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000, 1000000000 };


for (int number : numbersToFormat) {
  System.out.println(  
    NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.getDefault()).format(number));
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1
10
100
10,000
100,000
1,000,000
10,000,000
100,000,000
1,000,000,000
```

Answer (score 4):

Add this function in common class

```
  public static String getFormatedNumber(String number){
        if(!number.isEmpty()) {
            double val = Double.parseDouble(number);
            return NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(val);
        }else{
            return "0";
        }
    }
```

And use that function every where like this:

```
String newNumber = Utils.getFormatedNumber("10000000");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Numberformat

```
public static double getNumberByString(String s) throws ParseException {
    return NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault()).parse(s).doubleValue();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a text change listener as below (Also make sure that the input type selected for Edittext is Number) :

```
etTest.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        boolean isManualChange = false;

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            if (isManualChange) {
                isManualChange = false;
                return;
            }

            try {
                String value = s.toString().replace(",", "");
                String reverseValue = new StringBuilder(value).reverse()
                        .toString();
                StringBuilder finalValue = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 1; i <= reverseValue.length(); i++) {
                    char val = reverseValue.charAt(i - 1);
                    finalValue.append(val);
                    if (i % 3 == 0 && i != reverseValue.length() && i > 0) {
                        finalValue.append(",");
                    }
                }
                isManualChange = true;
                etTest.setText(finalValue.reverse());
                etTest.setSelection(finalValue.length());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Do nothing since not a number
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String formatNumber(int number){
    return NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.getDefault()).format(number);
}
public static String formatNumber(String number){
    return NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.getDefault()).format(Integer.parseInt(number));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Recommended and preferred way is to do it with the `strings.xml` file

```
<string name="format_denominated">%,d</string>
```

from your Kotlin/Java code

```
getResources().getString(R.string.format_denominated, value)
```

Even better with databinding

```
<TextView
    android:text="@{@string/format_denominated(value)}"
    ............/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this Kotlin extension function may can help.

```
fun String.formatPoint(): String {
    val sb = StringBuilder()
    this.reversed().forEachIndexed { index, c ->
        // 123,123,123
        if ((index + 1) % 3 == 0) {
            if (index != this.length - 1) {
                sb.append("$c,")
            } else {
                sb.append(c)
            }
        } else {
            sb.append(c)
        }
    }

    return sb.toString().reversed()
}
```