# How to add Comma between numbers

Tags: android

I have this code for my calculator:

```
            public void onClick(View v) {

            try {

                double price = Double.parseDouble(InputPrice.getText()
                        .toString());
                double percent = Double.parseDouble(InputPercent.getText()
                        .toString());

                double priceValue = price * percent / 100.0f;
                double percentValue = price - priceValue;

                PriceToGet.setText(String.valueOf(priceValue));
                PriceToPay.setText(String.valueOf(percentValue));

                PriceToGet.setText(String.format("%.02f", priceValue));
                PriceToPay.setText(String.format("%.02f", percentValue));
```

The Input and the Output are coming without commas like this:

Input: 333333333

Output: 134555.44

Output: 17475.66

This was just an example for Output and Input.

**How do I like the user see them is:**

Input: 333,333,333

Output: 134,555.44

Output: 17,475.66

Thanks

**Update:**

I added decimal in my onclick code:

```
                    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###");
```

I used this code but its closing the App after I press the button:

```
                    String PriceToGet = formatter.format(String.format("%.02f", priceValue));
```

And when I am using this method:

```
                    String PriceToGet = formatter.format("%.02f", priceValue);
```

Its force me to change it to:

```
String PriceToGet = formatter.format(priceValue);
```

What to do?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `DecimalFormat`

You will find the complete answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788113/how-can-i-format-a-string-number-to-have-commas-in-android-edit-field)

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can convert one of your integers to strings.

```
int x = 1000000;
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###"); 
String number_string = formatter.format(x);
System.out.println(number_string);
// Outputs 1,000,000
```

Comment: How does it work if there are more than for example 10 digits?

Comment: Plus this is giving me 100 000 000 instead of 100,000,000 :(

Comment: `number_string.replaceAll( "\\s+", "\\," )`fixed my problem.

Answer (score -3):

This JS function from Css Tricks -  http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/comma-values-in-numbers/

```
 function CommaFormatted(amount) {
    var delimiter = ","; // replace comma if desired
    var a = amount.split('.',2)
    var d = a[1];
    var i = parseInt(a[0]);
    if(isNaN(i)) { return ''; }
    var minus = '';
    if(i < 0) { minus = '-'; }
    i = Math.abs(i);
    var n = new String(i);
    var a = [];
    while(n.length > 3) {
        var nn = n.substr(n.length-3);
        a.unshift(nn);
        n = n.substr(0,n.length-3);
    }
    if(n.length > 0) { a.unshift(n); }
    n = a.join(delimiter);
    if(d.length < 1) { amount = n; }
    else { amount = n + '.' + d; }
    amount = minus + amount;
    return amount;
}
```

Comment: worked for me.  Can I get some feedback on the neg votes?

Comment: javascript != java

Comment: ha ha - that explains why the answers didnt work for me!