# Format number in kotlin with commas

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm pretty new to kotlin and would like to know how to format a number with commas.

Currently, my textview shows a number without any commas, i.e, 15000.
I want it to show 15,000 instead.

Here's my code that I want to format:

```
  txtTotalActive.text = it.statewise[0].active
```

"it.statewise[0].active" is an object that shows number but as I said, it shows without any commas.

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788113/how-can-i-format-a-string-number-to-have-commas-in-android-edit-field

Comment: @iCantC I get this java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number

Comment: Are you sure, `it.statewise[0].active` contains a number ?

Comment: @iCantC yes, I'm sure

Comment: Please share your logtrace

Comment: @iCantC I fixed it, check my edit. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of adding the solution in the question itself, please post the solution in the answer section.

Comment: @iCantC done, check

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
            var inoutValue = it.statewise[0].active
            val number = java.lang.Double.valueOf(inoutValue)
            val dec = DecimalFormat("#,###,###")
            val finalOutput = dec.format(number)

            txtTotalActive.text = finalOutput
```

Comment: Since this is the solution to your question, marked this solution as accepted. Future readers may benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

"%,.2f".format(text.toFloat())  <,> = grouping , 2 = precision/number of decimals after "."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).